# ms access - sql rewrite

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I have the following sql. First part (or subquery) find MAX date between 4 tables and then add the rest row values.

```
SELECT t1.Maxdate, 0 As TempZero, "John" As TempRec FROM (
    SELECT MAX([AppDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblApp 
    UNION SELECT MAX([FinDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblFin
    UNION SELECT MAX([ExpDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblExp 
    UNION SELECT MAX([OriDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblCus
) As t1
UNION 
SELECT t2.Maxdate, 0 As TempZero, "Alex" As TempRec FROM (
    SELECT MAX([AppDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblApp 
    UNION SELECT MAX([FinDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblFin
    UNION SELECT MAX([ExpDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblExp 
    UNION SELECT MAX([OriDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblCus
) As t2
UNION 
SELECT t3.Maxdate, 0 As TempZero, "Mary" As TempRec FROM (
    SELECT MAX([AppDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblApp 
    UNION SELECT MAX([FinDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblFin
    UNION SELECT MAX([ExpDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblExp 
    UNION SELECT MAX([OriDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblCus
) As t3
UNION 
SELECT t4.Maxdate, 0 As TempZero, "Peter" As TempRec FROM (
    SELECT MAX([AppDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblApp 
    UNION SELECT MAX([FinDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblFin
    UNION SELECT MAX([ExpDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblExp 
    UNION SELECT MAX([OriDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblCus
) As t4

… And continues to t12 the same code, simply change the [TempRec].
```

Is there an alternative way to write this code?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with this code. Edit question to show sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an equivalent fo DUAL for MS access ..
Just create a table DUAL with a single coulmn eg: field  and just add  a single rows  with a value eg: 'X'

then you could use this trick  for build query  where you have only value not based  on column contents

do the fact the values see always the same  in this case 
You could use a CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT t1.Maxdate, 0 As TempZero, t2.TempRec FROM (
    SELECT MAX([AppDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblApp 
    UNION SELECT MAX([FinDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblFin
    UNION SELECT MAX([ExpDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblExp 
    UNION SELECT MAX([OriDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblCus
) t1 , (

  select  "John" As TempRec
  from dual
  UNION  
  select  "Alex" 
  from dual
  UNION  
  select  "Mary" 
  from dual
  UNION  
  select  "Peter" 
  from dual  
) t2
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this. I am getting an error on DUAL.

Comment: @YvetteLee  correct  ms access  have not a "DUAL" table but you can easy create an equivalent one  for this porpouse..  hope is clear

Comment: Why not create a tblTempRec table with only a column TempRec that contains 12 rows with all the names (and use that instead of subquery t2)?

Comment: @WolfgangKais  good suggestion  .. you could post an answer  with this  ..

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UNION` query (*qryMaxDate*) for the 4 maximum values:

```
SELECT MAX([AppDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblApp 
UNION
SELECT MAX([FinDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblFin
UNION
SELECT MAX([ExpDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblExp 
UNION
SELECT MAX([OriDate]) As MaxDate FROM tblCus
```

and create a table *tblTempRec* with just one column *TempRec* that will hold the names:

[image]

Then, your final query would look like this:

```
SELECT q.Maxdate, 0 As TempZero, t.TempRec
FROM qryMaxDate q, tblTempRec t
```